# Calculate mean based on time horizons

Tags: r, dataframe, range, subset, mean

considering the following data.frame I would like to calculate the mean between 2011-01-03 and 2011-01-06:

```
             GOOG.Open GOOG.High GOOG.Low GOOG.Close GOOG.Volume
2011-01-03    297.94    302.49   297.94     301.87          NA
2011-01-04    302.51    302.79   299.76     300.76          NA
2011-01-05    299.73    304.86   299.72     304.23          NA
2011-01-06    305.03    308.91   304.72     306.44          NA
```

The result of the code `mean(data$GOOG.Open, seq(from=01/03/11, to=01/06/11))` gives me 529.8661 and is actually referencing to different values in the Data Frame. Do you know how to calculate the mean?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define how you have your data stored see: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

I'm using `dplyr` within the `tidyverse` package to analyse the data and `lubridate` to define the date formats. This assumes that you want to be able to vary the dates averaged.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat <- data.frame(date = c('2011-01-03','2011-01-04','2011-01-05','2011-01-06'), 
                  GOOG.Open = c(297.94,302.51,299.73,305.03))
dat %>% 
    mutate(date = format(ymd(date))) %>% 
    filter(date>='2011-01-03' & date<='2011-01-06') %>% 
    summarise(goog_mean = mean(GOOG.Open))
```

If you just want the mean of the data presented you can use:

```
mean(dat$GOOG.Open)
```

or

```
dat %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(GOOG.Open))
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the hint. I am downloading the data from google and the "dates" are actually the row names. Do you have an idea how I can reference to these dates, if they are not a column but rownames?